# Write email in newline to file in php

Tags: php

The user's email has to be written to a file and every email has to be on a newline. In my code, al the email are on the same line. Can't find it...
This is my **php**:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {

        $file = fopen("email.txt","a");

        $email = $_POST["email"];

        fwrite($file,"\n");
        fwrite($file,$email);


        fclose($file);
    }
```

Comment: I believe `"\r\n"` is the correct format of a new line in this case ....

Comment: @davidkonrad: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: In fact `\n` is fine if you use a better text editor than Notepad to view the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP_EOL which outputs \r\n or \n depending on the OS(only for UNIX/LINUX/Windows)

If you want to support all OS use "\r\n"

Comment: But what about the person who will read the email on a different OS?

Comment: Not exactly. If you send an email from a Unix system, the PHP constant `PHP_EOL` uses `\n`, which is equal to ASCII 10. But if the recipient uses Mac pre-OSX, the ASCII for linebreaks are ASCII 13, or `\r`. So the recipient can't understand the newline, because it expects a newline to be of ASCII 13, not ASCII 10 which is used.

Comment: oops, I considered only about unix and windows system.. I'll edit my answer accordingly